# chrome browser hangs when loading youtube playlists

Tags: google-chrome, youtube, chromecast

Anybody experience this issue with the chrome browser?

I loaded chrome on my Windows 8 tablet pc so I could use chromecast. Logged into my youtube account.
Then clicked on 'Playlists' link and chrome just hangs forever saying 'Loading..."

Through Firefox on the same system I have no problem trying to do the exact same thing.

Anybody know what's going on and what to do?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why have you tagged this with chromecast? Based on your question, it doesn't seem to be getting there.

Comment: I thought the issue might be related to the chromecast software plugin for the chrome browser which i installed. Regardless, the issue went away after I rebooted and re-launched chrome. Never figured out what the initial problem was but now I am able to play videos from my Playlist on my TV via chromecast, which is cool.